# how to change date format using timepicker update only

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have a date mm/dd/yyyy this is a formatting TimePicker I want to keep it that way, so it's time to change the table the timestamp does not work I want to trade for yyyy/mm/dd

Answer (score 1):

`$date = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($date_value_from_timepicker));`

Answer (score 0):

Very easy you need to convert the date using strtotime, in the example below is picking up the $ _POST variable method

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_POST['old_date']));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 //you need to change it to yyyy-mm-dd format
 $date_picker="05/24/2013";
 $date_st=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($date_picker));
```